# Problem with Mysql Connector/J 8.0.17(com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver ) and Tomcat 9

Tags: mysql, tomcat

I am using Connector 8.0.17 , when running simple java application this is working fine. But when I have created Servlet Application and deploying it on Tomcat server 9.0 and running application then Following exception comming :

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver atorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1363) at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1186) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)

### Any suggestion , really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hi All finally i got solution :
Download connector mysql-connector-java-8.0.17 and put it inside tomcat library :
D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.20\lib
And restart server and run application it will work properly.